# What are these character sequences in connection with DTMF and a modem (telephony)?

Tags: telephone, modem

I have a telephone, with which I dial a modem (analog, no ISDN) in order to send DTMF tones. If basically works, I receive something!

For each key I press on the telephone I get a string like follows (e.g. key 4 pressed):

```
<DLE>/<DLE>4<DLE>4<DLE>~
```

`DLE` is ASCII 16(dec), and I [found out](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.tapi/2005-09/msg00085.html) that those different parts seem to have the following meaning:

```
<DLE>/    # DTMF start
<DLE>4    # key I pressed
<DLE>4    # same key again ???
<DLE>~    # DTMF stop
```

I searched the web for a document specifying this format, but did not find any hint except the link.

Can anyone point out to a proper documentation? Is this format correct? What about the repitition of the actual character, is it correct too? What about having it three times?

Comment: Do you have *any* documentation about this?

Comment: This is ancient tech. I have paper technical documentation for old US Robotics and Multitech modems which list command sets, register usage and so  on. However a quick flick through revealed nothing about DTMF and DLE.

Answer (score 1):

### The long defunct Hayes corporation's proprietary "AT" command set.

The DLE (ASCII Data Link Escape) character is used for reporting of received DTMF (i.e. non-control and non-data signals) by V22(etc) modems.

I guess the repetition is associated with the 95 ms default duration for DTMF tone generated by the ATDT command in Hayes modems. If the user holds the key down for longer than 95mS, multiple DLE "4" sequences are reported. This potentially allows the receiving equipment to distinguish long and short presses.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_and_Data_modes_%28modem%29)

### Standardization (the lack of)

Note that all this originated as a proprietary single-manufacturer "standard" which has been extended by other manufacturers without oversight by any standards body. You should expect poor documentation and *inconsistency*.

There may be some limited standardization in specific fields of use as the Hayes AT command set crept into other realms (e.g. GSM) but I doubt there's a single body overseeing the standardization of everything associated with AT commands in all fields of technology.

### Conclusion

For precise information you'd have to obtain information from the producer of the specific modem device (or chipset). Any other source of documentation is potentially misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to type ati3 (or some variation of ati 0-15)and find the modem chipset manufacturer.
[image: XCTU]

Then start sleuthing, many times companies don't have proper datasheets for their chipsets, or the chip buyer/modem manufacturer will have custom programs running on those chips.  Look through all Multitech datasheets, especially the ones for the -V modems.  Some times you can find your chip, or one that uses similar commands.

In my experience, dtmf detection usually only works within a voice command set, and in voice mode.  Likely the special dle and handling are set up that way so dtmf tones can be picked out of raw audio data.

Count yourself lucky.  Its hit or miss whether or not modems reliably recognize dtmf tones.